# Haproxy Route Traffic Based on Querystring

Tags: haproxy

I want to config Haproxy to route traffic based on querystring. In particular...

1. If /lookup is in the URL, go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
2. If /related and ?loc= is in the url, go to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
3. If /related and no ?loc=, go to zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for `urlp` (aka `url_param`) to fetch sample from query string.

Something like this perhaps?

```
acl lookup path_beg /lookup
acl related path_beg /related
acl loc urlp(loc) -m found

use_backend xxx if lookup
use_backend yyy if related loc
use_backend zzz if related !loc
```

**NOTE**: `lookup` and `related` ACLs check if the URL **begins** with the path (*not "in the" path*). Also `loc` ACL checks if the query parameter **exists** even if it's empty. You need to change it a bit if it doesn't exactly fit your case.